# MS Access SQL combine multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have two tables in MS Access 2016 as shown below:

Table:**Table1**

```
         
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
----------------------------------------
   1    |    A    |      P   |   S
   1    |    B    |      J   |   J
   1    |    C    |      P   |   S
   1    |    D    |      S   |   P
   2    |    E    |      S   |   P
   2    |    F    |      P   |   S
   2    |    G    |      P   |   S
   2    |    H    |      S   |   P
   2    |    K    |      J   |   J
```

Table: **Table2**

```
Column5 |   Column6 |   Column7 |   Column8
--------------------------------------------------
    1   |       Z   |       i   |   Supplier
    1   |       Z   |       ii  |   Supplier
    1   |       Z   |       iii |   Supplier
    1   |       Z   |       iv  |   Supplier
    1   |       Z   |       v   |   Supplier
    1   |       Z   |       vi  |   Joint
    1   |       Z   |       vii |   Joint
    1   |       Y   |       viii|   Joint
    1   |       Y   |       ix  |   Supplier
    1   |       L   |       x   |   Supplier
    1   |       L   |       xi  |   Supplier
    1   |       L   |       xii |   Supplier
    2   |       W   |       xx  |   Joint
    2   |       W   |       xxi |   Joint
    2   |       W   |       xxii|   Joint
    2   |       W   |      xxiii|   Joint
    2   |       W   |      xxiv |   Joint
    2   |       M   |       xv  |   Supplier
```

Is there a way to merge the tables as shown below. The rows should not be repeating.If a cell exist in Table2 and not in 1, leave the cell blank in the result

**Query Result:**

```
Column1 |   Column2 |   Column3 |   Column4 |   Column5 |   Column6 |   Column7 |   Column8
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    1   |   A       |       P   |       S   |       1   |       Z   |       i   |Supplier
    1   |   B       |       J   |       J   |       1   |       Z   |       ii  |Supplier
    1   |   C       |       P   |       S   |       1   |       Z   |       iii |Supplier
    1   |   D       |       S   |       P   |       1   |       Z   |       iv  |Supplier
    1   |           |           |           |       1   |       Z   |       v   |Supplier
    1   |           |           |           |       1   |       Z   |       vi  |Joint
    1   |           |           |           |       1   |       Z   |       vii |Joint
    1   |           |           |           |       1   |       Y   |       viii|Joint
    1   |           |           |           |       1   |       Y   |       ix  |Supplier
    1   |           |           |           |       1   |       L   |       x   |Supplier
    1   |           |           |           |       1   |       L   |       xi  |Supplier
    1   |           |           |           |       1   |       L   |       xii |Supplier
    2   |   E       |       S   |       P   |       2   |       W   |       xx  |Joint
    2   |   F       |       P   |       S   |       2   |       W   |       xxi |Joint
    2   |   G       |       P   |       S   |       2   |       W   |       xxii|Joint
    2   |   H       |       S   |       P   |       2   |       W   |     xxiii |Joint
    2   |   K       |       J   |       J   |       2   |       W   |       xxiv|Joint
    2   |           |           |           |       2   |       M   |       xv  |Supplier
```

Comment: Can you also describe the join logic which generates your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution :

```
SELECT Column5 AS Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8 
FROM 
     (SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,
      @rownumber:=IF(@lastId=Column1,@rownumber+1,1) AS RowNumber,
      @lastId:=Column1
      FROM Table1,
      (Select @rownumber:=0,@lastId:=MIN(Column1) FROM TABLE1 ) AS r) AS Tbl1
RIGHT JOIN 
      (SELECT Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,
       @rownumber:=IF(@lastId=Column5,@rownumber+1,1) AS RowNumber,
       @lastId:=Column5
       FROM Table2, 
       (Select @rownumber:=0,@lastId:=MIN(Column5) FROM TABLE2 ) AS r) AS Tbl2
ON Tbl1.Column1 = Tbl2.Column5
AND Tbl1.RowNumber = Tbl2.RowNumber
```

Follow the below link for demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bcd6/25